# Delayed / animated scroll presentation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, effects, presentation

Anyone knows what I can use to create an scroll effect like the one of this website? https://www.kissthebride.fr/

When mouse wheel is used the presentation pages are shown one by one and the user is forced to stay some seconds at least on the page (if he doesn't use the right navigation).

I built my site using React. It has a pinned site navigation menu on the left, a pinned page navigation menu (to navigate through the current presentation pages) on the right and the main content on the middle. I need to apply this effect to the main content only and keep the right and left parts as they are.

Comment: Skrollr and ScrollMagic are two plugins made specifically for such purposes - https://ihatetomatoes.net/skrollr-vs-scrollmagic/

Answer (score 0):

[The effect itself](https://github.com/Xaxis/jquery.scrollfire)

[Animation ideas](https://codepen.io/pens/)

```
.
```